# React + Springboot or Springboot only for a project?

Tags: javascript, java, project

My partner and I are building a project for a class this semester. I am currently doing research on what technologies we want to use. So far Springboot for the server side and MySQL or Postgres for the database are strong contenders. I wanted to ask if we should use React or even Angular for our frontend or should we just develop multiple JSP pages for our frontend? So far in my research I have not seen many people combine React and Springboot for projects and it makes me think perhaps I am combining two things not really meant to be combined. Can anybody assist us in deciding the tech stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever write server-side rendered user interfaces. Create a REST api for your backend so that you can have multiple clients querying such api: today, a web app written in angular or react,  tomorrow maybe a mobile version.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first project on this scale even though its not something that would be industry level but still hard enough for a beginner like me. A follow up question though, is Springboot + Tomcat + React/Angular + SQL database a fine stack for us to use? Just to cover the backend, frontend, and database. Like this is not a bad combination or a weird one?

Comment: It's the business need that dictates the technologies to use. The stack you want to use is quite a common choice and will get you to work with widespread technologies so I think it's fine for you to use it for learning

Answer (score 1):

It depends on so many factors. Some of them are the speed at which you want to finish the project and the quality of the project.

It is a good idea to learn at least one framework and Spring is a good fit.

Regarding the front end, JSP is not a good idea. Both Angular and React are fine as long as you want to learn and develop yourselves. Something in the middle, which may be a bit easier to digest would be Vue.js. Any of these would require a lot of time investment. Since you are already planning to learn Spring and Java then you may use a template engine to make your life easier, something like Thymeleaf. This is a bit old school but it may help you achieve faster results with what you already have.

You also have the option to go on the Javascript or Python directions.

There is no really good answer here, it all depends on what you know, what you want to learn, what you hope to achieve and, of course, the end result.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do want to learn React or Angular since they are very popular. I think this is a fine learning opportunity.